# PHP Regular Expression to match these three strings

Tags: php, regex

I need to check if any strings follow the same format as these.

```
Val-Pak
*Client Referral*
Gift Certificate
```

It needs to be done in regular expression. I can't find how to include the * and -.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_grep('/Val-Pak|\*Client Referral\*|Gift Certificate/', $myArray);
```

[`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) filters an array of strings and returns only those that contain one of the strings you mentioned. If you need to check only a single string, then [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) will do.

If you need to escape arbitrary strings for inclusion in a regex pattern, then [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) comes in handy.

In any case, the asterisk, `*`, is a special character in regular expressions and needs to be escaped with a `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for information on how to write Regex (regular expressions), it goes through how to escape characters like * and -

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is you escape them with backslashes:

```
/Val\-Pak/

/\*Client\sReferral\*/

/Gift\sCertificate/
```

But it might help to read some regex tutorials, because understanding the big picture will help you in the long run.